# Python3 after cursor.execute it stopped?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

After much trying on python3 (as of still new in this language), the line whereby **cursor.execute** will prevent the for loop to continue when condition met. However when I comment **cursor.execute** line, the looping able to continue until the end. How can I made it continue till the last result of the loop?

**Objective to achieve: -**
I am trying to filter a bunch of data from CFC_xxxx table, process and put it back into SENSOR_TREEHUGGERS table.

**Line where the show stopper happened: -**

> cursor.execute(sqlInsert,
>   (xxGatewayId,qqqGatewayId,treeDiameter,temperature,recordTime,dateTime,treeHuggerID))

**Python3 Code: -**

```
import base64
import struct
import pymysql.cursors
import sys 
import datetime
from contextlib import closing

connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                user='xxx',
                password='xxx',
                db='xxx',
                charset='utf8mb4',
                cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

with closing(connection.cursor()) as cursor:
 sql = "SELECT * FROM CFC_xxxx"
 cursor.execute(sql)
 for row in cursor:
  check = struct.unpack('>15x2f4B1L1x', base64.b64decode(row['Value']))

  if check[6] > 20000 or check[6] < 10000:
   continue
  else:
   xxGatewayId = int(row['Node_ID'])
   qqqGatewayId = int(row['Gateway_ID'])
   treeDiameter = int(check[0])
   temperature = int(check[1])
   recordTime = str(row['Timestamp'])
   year = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(row['Timestamp']).strftime('%Y')
   if check[2] == 0:
    hours = '00'
   else:
    hours = str(check[2])

   if check[3] == 0:
    minute = '00'
   else:
    minute = str(check[3])

   if check[4] < 10: 
    day = '0'+str(check[4])
   else:
    day = str(check[4])

   if check[5] < 10: 
    month = '0'+str(check[5])
   else:
    month = str(check[5])

   dateTime = str(year + '-' + month + '-' + day + ' ' + hours + ':' + minute + ':00')
   treeHuggerID = int(check[6])

   sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO SENSOR_TREEHUGGERS(`xx_Gateway_Id`,`qqq_Gateway_Id`,`treeDiameter`,`temperature`,`recordTime`,`dateTime`,`TreeHuggerId`) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
   cursor.execute(sqlInsert, (xxGatewayId,qqqGatewayId,treeDiameter,temperature,recordTime,dateTime,treeHuggerID))
   connection.commit()
```

Comment: You'd need to elaborate on that, I don't get what you are trying to do, or what is happening

Comment: @Lazik, just added in the objective to achieve.

Comment: The thing is you have 2 cursor.execute lines, so which one is causing problem? I mean be more specific with the code flow, which line is behaving unexpectedly

Comment: @Lazik, ops my bad. It was supposed the `cursor.execute(sqlInsert, (xxGatewayId,qqqGatewayId,treeDiameter,temperature,recordTime,dateTime,treeHuggerID))` on the last second row. Added into the description on top. Thanks for reminding.

Comment: Does it say anything? Is there an exception?

Comment: Got it solved after some hardcore trying > <'
Will post the answer... (python3..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is how I get my trouble solved. Using **array** to append all the processed data and use **executemany** to save them at once. In beforehand, have to modify mysql config **max_allowed_packet = 500M**

A pain but valuable lesson.

**Answer: -**

```
import base64
import struct
import pymysql.cursors
import sys 
import datetime
from contextlib import closing

collectData = []
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                user='xxx',
                password='xxx',
                db='xxx',
                charset='utf8mb4',
                cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

with closing(connection.cursor()) as cursor:
 sql = "SELECT * FROM CFC_xxxx"
 cursor.execute(sql)
 for row in cursor:
  check = struct.unpack('>15x2f4B1L1x', base64.b64decode(row['Value']))

  if check[6] > 20000 or check[6] < 10000:
   continue
  else:
   xxGatewayId = int(row['Node_ID'])
   qqqGatewayId = int(row['Gateway_ID'])
   treeDiameter = int(check[0])
   temperature = int(check[1])
   recordTime = str(row['Timestamp'])
   year = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(row['Timestamp']).strftime('%Y')
   if check[2] == 0:
    hours = '00'
   else:
    hours = str(check[2])

   if check[3] == 0:
    minute = '00'
   else:
    minute = str(check[3])

   if check[4] < 10: 
    day = '0'+str(check[4])
   else:
    day = str(check[4])

   if check[5] < 10: 
    month = '0'+str(check[5])
   else:
    month = str(check[5])

   dateTime = str(year + '-' + month + '-' + day + ' ' + hours + ':' + minute + ':00')
   treeHuggerID = int(check[6])
   collectData.append(xxGatewayId,qqqGatewayId,treeDiameter,temperature,recordTime,dateTime,treeHuggerID)

  c1 = connection.cursor()
  sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO  SENSOR_TREEHUGGERS(`xx_Gateway_Id`,`qqq_Gateway_Id`,`treeDiameter`,`temperature`,`recordTime`,`dateTime`,`TreeHuggerId`) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
  c1.executemany(sqlInsert, collectData)
  connection.commit()
```